# How to call each value of a dictionary by its key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to separate each (key, value) pair from a dictionary and want to call each value by its key name.

I have two lists,

```
1. ListA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2. ListB = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Now I have created a dictionary like this,

```
Dict = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E'}
```

So, now if I want to see value for each key, I have to type:
`Dict[key]`.

Now I expect my result to be like:
If I ask for the value of each key, I have to just type `key` not `Dict[key]`
and it should give me the answer.

Typing `1` should give `A`.
Typing `2` should give `B`.

Comment: Use `int(input())` to get the key from user and print with `Dict[user_input]`.

Comment: Why this but treating `1` as `A` why?

Answer (score 0):

You can somehow do like this but you if you can simply access below is not a very good idea honestly. You can set key as attribute of an object.

But it wont work for the dictionary you have my Input Dictionary is `{"key1":"Apple"}`

```
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self,input_dict):
        for key,value in input_dict.items():
            setattr(self,key,value) #setting key as attribute

obj = MyDict({"key1":"Apple"}) #new instance                    
print(obj.key1) # this will print Apple
```

But still it wont work like `obj.1` better not to mess it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *loop* over dictionary values, you can use `Dict.values()`:

```
for v in Dict.values():
    print(v)

# > 'A'
# > 'B'
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a while true loop, keep popping items from your lists until you run into an IndexError like this:

```
ListA = [1, 2, 3]
ListB = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
DictC = {}

while True:
   try:
     DictC[ListA.pop(0)] = ListB.pop(0)
   except IndexError:
     break

print(DictC)
```